# Android > How to get service state for both sim cards in dual sim device?

Tags: android, cellinfo

I need it for API 22 and above.
I saw that we have `telephonyManager.getServiceState` - but I don't know how to get it for sim1 and for sim2 exactly.
Also we have CellInfo.serviceState - but it's only from API 28.

How to get it? I don't need any listeners, I just want to get service state at the certain time

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researches, implemented this solution:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "NewApi")
    private fun getServiceState(simSlotNmb: Int): String {
        try {
            val serviceState: ServiceState?
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                serviceState = if (subscriptionManager != null && subscriptionManager!!.activeSubscriptionInfoCount > 1) {
                        val subsId =
                            subscriptionManager!!.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(
                                simSlotNmb
                            ).subscriptionId
                        val telephonyManager =
                            (context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager)
                                .createForSubscriptionId(subsId)

                        telephonyManager.serviceState
                    } else {
                        telephonyManager.serviceState
                    }
            } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && subscriptionManager != null
                      && subscriptionManager!!.activeSubscriptionInfoCount > 1) {
                val subsId = subscriptionManager!!.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(simSlotNmb).subscriptionId
                val telephonyManagerForSlot
                        = (context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager)
                        .createForSubscriptionId(subsId)
                telephonyManagerForSlot.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE)
                telephonyManagerForSlot.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE)
                serviceState = latestServiceState
            } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && subscriptionManager != null
                && subscriptionManager!!.activeSubscriptionInfoCount > 1) {
                val noConnectionDbm = -110
                val dbm = getSignalDbm(simSlotNmb)
                serviceState = ServiceState()
                if(dbm < noConnectionDbm) {
                    serviceState.state = ServiceState.STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE
                } else {
                    serviceState.state = ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE
                }
            } else {
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE)
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE)
                serviceState = latestServiceState
            }
            return when (serviceState?.state) {
                ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE -> "in service"
                ServiceState.STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY -> "emergency only"
                else -> "out of service"
            }
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            exc.printStackTrace()

            return when(exc) {
                is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -> "out of service"
                else -> Constants.error
            }
        }
    }
```